# JQuery/AJAX: How to pass variables to some JS-API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with passing JS-defined Variables from an AJAX response to a JS-API, namely Googles jsapi. What I want to do is display a chart using this API and then use AJAX from time to time to reload the values from a database.
So far, everything works just fine. But as I return these variables by AJAX - how can I get JS to parse the result?

The code:

```
<div id="t">
    xyz
</div>
<script>
    window.setInterval(function()
    {
        $.post('mod/script.php', function(data) { $('#t').html(data) } );
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Where script.php would return values like

```
echo "data.addRows($datasets);";
echo "data.setValue($i, 0, '$date $time');";
```

Problem is, that I dont know, which values are returned by the script. This depends on what is currently stored in the database.

How to do this right? I have some ideas, but I wonder what is the most convenient way here...

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to execute certain JS callbacks in the context of the current document, is that right?

The proper way would be [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

A really really really quirky "alternative" would be to do this in your script.php:

```
echo "(function(){";
echo "data.addRows($datasets);";
echo "data.setValue($i, 0, '$date $time');";
echo "})()";
```

and have this callback:

```
 $.post('mod/script.php', function(callback){ eval(callback); });
```

Also, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EsytA/1/